# Python parse string date

Tags: python, date, iso

I have string like this:

```
2019-04-03 05:10:35+03:00
```

I need to output date like this:

```
2019-04-03 08:10:35
```

My code:

```
print(datetime.strptime(str("2019-04-03 05:10:35+03:00"), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S%z"))
```

but I have error:

> ValueError: time data '2019-04-03 05:10:35+03:00' does not match
>   format '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S%z'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your input string is improperly formatted. `%z` expects a string of format `+HHMM` or `-HHMM`; you have an extra `:`.

Accordingly, you could use a regex to format it:

```
import re

source = '2019-04-03 05:10:35+03:00'
formatted = re.sub(r'([+-])(\d\d):(\d\d)', r'\1\2\3', source)

print(datetime.strptime(formatted, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S%z").astimezone(timezone.utc).strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))
```

Output:

```
2019-04-03 02:10:35
```

Comment: The output is incorrect.

Comment: thanks for answer! How i can output instead `2019-04-03 05:10:35+03:00` date like this `2019-04-03 08:10:35` (plus or minus hours)

Comment: @nesalexy To clarify, is your expected output `08:10:35` or `02:10:35`? (since +03:00 normally implies that the given time is *ahead* of UTC)

Comment: The output is still incorrect.

Comment: @DirtyBit I may have misunderstood the question, then...

Comment: @gmds honestly if we take date like this `2019-04-03 05:10:35+03:00` i thought we need +3 hrs. For example if our date like this `2019-04-03 05:10:35-03:00` i thought we need -3hrs

Comment: @nesalexy If you say the time now is 10 PM UTC+8, the only other conventional way to represent it would be in UTC, which would be 2 PM. To put it another way, the `+03:00` after the time normally signifies a *timezone* in relation to UTC. For you to interpret it as an *offset stored in the same piece of data* instead is not wrong, but it's a little unusual, so it would be good to get some clarity on what your actual usecase is.

Answer (score 2):

This will work

```
from datetime import datetime

your_date = datetime.strptime("2019-04-03 05:10:35+03:00", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S%z")

print(your_date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))
```

[image]

**EDIT:**

You have "+03:00" if you count timezone, if you want to add that to your result, do it like this:

```
from datetime import datetime
your_date = datetime.strptime("2019-04-03 05:10:35+03:00", "%Y-%m-%d%H:%M:%S%z")
print((your_date + timedelta(0, your_date.tzinfo.utcoffset(your_date).seconds)).strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))
```

[image]

Comment: Nope, incorrect output.

Comment: Edited the answer, now it has both things

Answer (score 1):

Using `datetime` and `split()` for `str` manipulation:

Assuming it to be `+` hours:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

dt_1 = "2019-04-03 05:10:35+03:00"
date_ = dt_1.split("+")[0]
time_ = date_.split(" ")[1]
to_add = dt_1.split("+")[1]

d = datetime.strptime(date_, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
t = datetime.strptime(time_, "%H:%M:%S")
d += timedelta(hours=int(to_add.split(":")[0]), minutes=int(to_add.split(":")[1]))

print(d)
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
2019-04-03 08:10:35
```